# what is "in a game of 'who's who'"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-usage

I'm not sure the meaning of the following sentence.

He has worked in a game of "who's who" with specialists in his field.

what do you mean by  "to work in a game of 'who's who'"?

Answer (score 3):

I can't say for sure without more context, but:

A "Who's Who" is a book that lists prominent or important people, typically with a brief biography. There are many such books published by a variety of publishers.

From this, the term "Who's Who" has come to mean a group of important people. Like someone will say, "The attendees at the party were practically a Who's Who of powerful politicians".

I'm not sure what someone would mean by "a game of Who's Who". It sounds like he means that people are competing in some way. Perhaps competing to see who knows or has worked with the most important people? Or perhaps the point isn't the "game" part, but simply that this person has worked with many important specialists in the field.

Comment: We must have posted at the same time. As we said more or less the same thing and you got in first by a couple of minutes, I've deleted mine. I included a bit more background that I'll paste here for completeness: The original Who's who is a book of biographies of famous or influential people and has been published annually in the UK since 1849. It's still being printed today and you can buy the 2015 edition for $499 from the publisher Bloomsbury

Over the years there have been many copies, spin-offs and imitations, but being in Who's Who has become synonymous with being successful.

Comment: No quarrel with anything you say here. As an American when I think of Who's Who I think of Marquis, but whatever. I see in your deleted answer you include an interpretation I didn't think of: they might have been competing to see which of them should be in Who's Who or have the longest entry, as opposed to knowing people in Who's Who.